# C# Fire and Forget considerations

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety

I'm considering using a fire-and-forget pattern for sending emails from an ASP/C# application, so the user isn't waiting around while it does its thing. I've used the pattern before, pretty much like this article explains;

http://microsoftmentalist.com/2012/02/02/asp-netcall-synchronous-method-asynchronously-asp-net-fire-and-forget/

All very simple stuff, but I really need to know about the performance considerations. Am I supposed to just keep creating new threads every time I need to send an email, and just trust in the framework to manage them? Or is there a way i can manually put the thread back in the pool after it's finished?

Comment: The link appears to be bad.

Comment: Stephen C also has a good one here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO NOT starve the application's ThreadPool.  Instead, use [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) if you have a lot of threads to create in a single process.  There's a Fire & Forget example in the article.

But... the easiest way to pop off an email is to use QueueUserWorkItem:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => SendEmail(emailTo, emailFrom, emailSubject, emailBody));
```

You won't need to worry about putting the thread back in the threadpool.  Threadpool management is automatically handled via the framework when using the ThreadPool class.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would submit your work items using the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It will abstract away the proper pooling and management of threads so your application remains responsive and stable, and without the developer messing it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Code in the link you provided **is using the thread pool**, you do not need to care about it. It'll use a thread from a pool and it'll put the thread back to the pool after it's finished.